# an unindexed column, mysql error 'specified key was too long max key length is 767 bytes'

Tags: mysql

MySQL version is 5.6.23, why increase an unindexed column of varchar type, length from 1024 to 2048, MySQL prompts 'mysql error specified key was too long max key length is 767 bytes'.

I have checked the column(ccer) isn't indexed, the definition is that: `ccer` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '抄送人（name格式，多个用;隔开）'. Below is the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `send` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `createTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updateTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ccer` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '抄送人（name<address>格式，多个用;隔开）',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

I know if the column is indexed, the key's length is limited. But the column is not indexed, why is there this error?

After I executed the commands below:

```
set global innodb_large_prefix=1;
set global innodb_file_format=BARRACUDA;
```

I can extend the column `ccer` size from 1024 to 2048.

Comment: Do a `show create table` to show indexes on table; the indexes (or "keys" in the mysql parlance) are not included in a column definition. Missing from this question is the *actual* definition of the table, and the *actual* statement that was executed to attempt to "increase" length of a column. The limit of 767 bytes can be overridden by setting of `innodb_large_prefix` for some InnoDB row format. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-restrictions.html

Comment: @spencer7593  I have added the table definition.

Comment: You were altering the table. It failed. Reason: you *tried* to index `ccer`. You can't post `create table` which succeeds and then omit `alter table` that fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something else is going on. If a column is not included in any index, the we can modify the length of a character column to increase its length, without raising the max key length error.

Demonstration (note `innodb_large_prefix` is set to ON)

```
USE `test`
;
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'version'
;
-- Variable_name  Value
-- -------------  ---------------------------
-- version        5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-log

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_large_prefix'
;
-- Variable_name        Value   
-- -------------------  --------
-- innodb_large_prefix  ON
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE `send` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `createTime` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `updateTime` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  `ccer` VARCHAR(1024) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '抄送人（name<address>格式，多个用;隔开）',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
;

-- 0 row(s) affected
```

---

```
INSERT INTO `send` VALUES (NULL,NOW(),NOW(),'')
;

-- 1 row(s) affected
```

---

```
ALTER TABLE `send`
  CHANGE `ccer` `ccer` VARCHAR(2048) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '抄送人（name<address>格式，多个用;隔开）'
;

-- 0 row(s) affected
```

---

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE `send` ;

-- CREATE TABLE `send` (
--   `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
--   `createTime` datetime NOT NULL,
--   `updateTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
--   `ccer` varchar(2048) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '抄送人（name<address>格式，多个用;隔开）',
--   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
-- ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

---

I think there's something else going on, other than changing the definition of a column that is not included in an index.

Comment: @spncer7593  After I executed the commands below:
set global innodb_large_prefix=1;
set global innodb_file_format=BARRACUDA;
I can extend the column ccer size from 1024 to 2048.
I just don't know why.

Comment: we know the error relates to InnoDB storage engine, everyone uses file_per_table, so we're down to file format (legacy Antelope vs newer Barracuda) and the row format.  a frequent tripup is the characterset, multiple bytes per character) but doesn't appear to be the issue here, column is already1024 characters, with utf8mb4, that's maximum of 4096 bytes, which already exceeds the 767 byte limit . https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-row-format.html